# IE label disappears on Tab-key press

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, label

There are text-inputs with labels for them on the left side to each one. Only in Internet Explorer (9) on Tab-key press, focused on the next input field, its label disappears and the input field 'jumps' left by the value of its label width.

The html structure:

```
div
    display flex
    align-items center
    overflow hidden

label
    white-space nowrap
    width min-content
    padding-left 1px
span
    display inline-block
    width 100%
input 
    display inline-block
    width 100%
    margin-left 0
    box-sizing border-box
```

How is it possible to make IE keep the input's label on its place on Tab-key press?

It appears, inputs width 100% is calculated incorrectl, overflows the div. IE moves it all left to show the rest of input. How to eliminate this thing for IE?

Comment: Please provide a demo.

Comment: answer: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658344/195986